# knockout valueupdate:'afterkeydown' property is not working

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to run my first code on knockout on http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro and when i tried to use valueupdate property with "afterkeydown"
 it does change the label on key up/down event. Can someone please help what is wrong with this code.

```js
// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
function AppViewModel() {   
    firstName = ko.observable("Harsh");   
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(AppViewModel());
```

```html
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName, valueupdate:'afterkeydown'" /></p>
<p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is case sensitive and the knockout binding is `valueUpdate` not `valueupdate`.

You need to use `<input data-bind="value: firstName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />`

Also, if you want a better cross-browser support you can use the `textInput` binding to achieve the same thing.
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html